# How JavaScript execute the code and define variables?

Tags: javascript

I have just started to learn JS and trying to understand how it executes the code. If I run following code:

```
    console.log(a);

    var a = 'hello world'

    console.log(a);
```

The output for first line is 'undefined' and second line 'hello world'. My question is why JS didnt do either of these:

1) Throw me an error at first line that 'a is not defined' and then output 'hello world'.

2) I understand JS has two phases CREATION and EXECUTION, then in this case at the end of the creation phase JS knew that a value has been defined as 'hello world'. Why it didn't give out as 'hello world' for both console.log?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: The first variable is not defined (declared) yet then it gets declared and you can print it in second attempt

Comment: Only the variable creation, with an initial `undefined` value, is hoisted. The `a = 'hello world'` assignment is part of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

1) you have to write your own type of debugging when it comes to what you're asking for. The message "undefined" is the browser's way of saying "a is not defined"

2) the code will execute procedurally if it's not segmented into functions and executed through function calls

```
var a = "Hello World"; //this is execute first
console.log(a); //this will execute second


function outputVar () { console.log(a); } //function is initialized but not executed
var a = "Hello World"; //This will execute first
outputVar(); //This will call the initialized method that will reference the var that was set already.
```

What need to under stand is that all code will execute top to bottom in order, unless it is apart of some other initialized code waiting to be called e.x. Classes and Functions

Also keep in mind the level of access for variables. You might want to look into local and global variables to understand how you make data accessible by these initialized functions that are being called.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the code really looks like after the CREATION phase:

```
var a; // hoisted during the creation

console.log(a);
a = 'hello world'
console.log(a);
```